# How do I install 32-bit Mono in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 64-bit, 32-bit, mono

I have a Windows app that requires a 32-bit runtime to execute with Mono. I have installed Mono 5.x (a requirement, it can't use 6.x or later) from [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20190702192545/https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin) using these commands:

```
sudo apt install gnupg ca-certificates
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mono-devel
```

However, this only has 64-bit executables, and I can't use `mono --arch=32 executable.exe`. What is the best thing to do here?

I am using ARM64 Ubuntu Focal 20.04, for reference.

Comment: I do not know if that repository has 32-bit executables, or if mono supports 32-bit arches from 64-bit toolchains, but usually you need to ensure you have enabled 32-bit packages available on ubuntu you'll need the 32-bit architecture `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` (and then you'll need to `apt update`).  To install the 32-bit version of a package you suffix the architecture like so `sudo apt install mono-devel:i386`.  However not all tools behave sanely - eg if you have both 64-bit and 32-bit installed, so this may not be the right fix that you need.